# Yii2 grid filter dropdown additional option to arrayHelper

Tags: arrays, gridview, drop-down-menu, filter, yii2

I would like to add an **aggregating** option (*"All options"* in the example) to a dropdown filter in grid, that covers all other options, and looks like this:

```
All options
Option1
Option2
Option3
...
```

I have tried this way:

grid:

```
'filter' => ['All options', yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\RelatedModel::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),]
```

ModelSearch:

```
if ($this->RelatedModelId == 'All options') {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'RelatedModelId', \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn(RelatedModel::find()->all(), 'id')]);
    } else {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['RelatedModelId' => $this->RelatedModelId ,]);
    };
```

It works (maybe not the most beautiful solution of the world, but it's okay for me at the moment). The only thing that's disturbing me, is this `0` (or 1 sometimes, depending on how I change code) in the dropdown list:

```
All options
0
    Option1
    Option2
    Option3
    ...
```

And I know it's because of the brackets `[]` in filter (`'filter' => [...]`), but at the moment this is the only way I could achieve the functionality I need. I have no idea how to make it work witout the brackets. Is there a simple way (to put an additional tiny little option somwhow, somewhere maybe) not to show this `0` or do I have to do it completely different? It's not really a big problem that is looks like this, but would be better not to see it. Or can I put this `All` into the `map` function?

```
'filter' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(array_merge(['All options', app\models\RelatedModel::find()->all()]), 'id', 'name'),
```

I've also tried `array_merge()` but without a success.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
'filter' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\RelatedModel::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
```

will already render empty option (with no text) for resetting choice in this drop-down list.

For search just set:

```
$this->andWhere(['your_field_id' => $this->your_field_id]);
```

in your search model and you ready to go.

Also don't forget to add this attribute as safe attribute in `rules` section:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['your_field_id', 'safe'],
    ],
}
```

You can see an example in CRUD generator.

If you want to customize shown text, append `prompt` option to existing [yii\grid\DataColum $filterInputOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$filterInputOptions-detail):

```
'filterInputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => null, 'prompt' => 'All'],
```

Also by putting this in view you are violating MVC principle:

```
\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\RelatedModel::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
```

Either call this in a controller and pass as parameter to view or wrap in some `getList()` method.

Comment: Hi Master Arogachev, thanks for replying, but I'm afraid I haven't expressed myself clear enough then. I do not need an additional **empty** option, but an option what covers all other options. Violating? It's already so in Giiant, that's why I do it also this way.